# Difference between a "public" class and an unmodified class?

Tags: java, class, access-modifiers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [package visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471824/package-visibility)
>   [Java - The difference between class “ClassName” and public class “ClassName”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641876/java-the-difference-between-class-classname-and-public-class-classname)

Basically is there any difference in these two modifiers of classes? Is there any difference in not having the public modifier?

```
public class MyClass {}

class MyClass {}
```

Comment: @pst: OK, what about these ones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191022/what-are-variables-without-public-private-or-protected-declared-as, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996739/non-public-top-level-class-in-java, etc. They all treat the subject sufficiently. I'm sure I can find more. We could discuss this on meta, how "exact" a duplicate should be

Comment: @LukasEder No, that's about members, not classes.

Answer (score 1):

A `public` class is visible by any other class, while a `class` (without modifier) will have a package visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Default is package-private http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java-Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1):

*If a class or interface type is declared public, then it may be accessed by any code, provided that the compilation unit (§7.3) in which it is declared is observable.*

*If a top level class or interface type is not declared public, then it may be accessed only from within the package in which it is declared.*

Answer (score 0):

1.Public class is accessible from outside its  **package** whereas, class is not.
2.There can be only one public class in a **source file**, and the source file's name has to be same.